# Sending message to Singleton Object

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `Singleton Class` to perform Web Service operations. Suppose we have created a method `-(void)getProfilesWithName:(NSString *)profileName` to get some profile information. I am using `block` objects to get response back from `Web Service Operations` Class. Since `Web Service Operations` is singleton many objects can send the same `[self getProfilesWithName:@"John"]` messages at a time. In this scenario the first object that makes the Web Service request would not receive data .

What is the proper way to perform some Web Service Operations using a `Singleton Class` ? Can I use `NSOperationQueue` ?

Comment: Doesn't the answer depend on how the class does its work?  In which case please show how it works.

Answer (score 0):

`NSOperationQueue` is one possibility. `queue.addOperationWithBlock(_ block: () -> Void)` is the method which adds a new block. But I think you could do this without the queue. Do not set the block as an instance variable, use it directly in your success method or block.

Comment: The OP is using Objective-C, so `() -> Void` won't mean much to him,

Comment: `getProfilesWithName("profileName")` is swift or not? i first wrote objc and edited it

Comment: The question is tagged with `objective-c`, although you make a good point.